# Same output of KDF for Alice and Bob?

Tags: aes

Alice and Bob use the same password which will be used in a KDF like PBKDF2_HMAC or Argon2id to generate a AES-key. The problem is that Argon2id generates a different output for the same password, resulting in the AES-key being different for Alice and Bob.

Pseudo-code:

```
password = "abc123"

# For Alice
salt = randomsalt()
key = KDF(password, salt)
#Output: b089b4def6c3e443838a34c4c679c0fb81b708c613850c40910f4809fab5b679

aesKey = AES.new(key)
#AES for Alice: 2b7e151628aed2a6abf7158809cf4f3c


# For Bob
salt = randomsalt()
key = KDF(password, salt)
#Output: f1e7117fe494c4a01094b652ccccc9d38006fb8439a4144b6d9356348baddbef


aesKey = AES.new(key)
#AES for Bob: 3ad77bb40d7a3660a89ecaf32466ef97
```

Because the random salt for Alice and Bob is different, the KDF will generate a different output even for the same password. Because the derived key is different, they will have different AES keys and can't communicate with each other?

The context is a chat application which Alice and Bob can initiate by both entering the same password when they join the chat. Not entering the same password means they can not read each other's messages.

Currently I have solved this by generating the derived key server-side and send it to the connected clients. But is there a way to generated the derived key client-side?

Comment: You need to use KDF intended for [key stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching) and not for password hashing, i.e. use the KDF which is intended for the purpose you need instead of trying to use something with a different purpose and then wonder why it does not work. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function for the differences.

Comment: Isn't Argon used for key stretching?

Comment: Yes, but you have to make the random component you have (the salt) predictable. See [Encrypt a file with AES using a secret key derived with Argon2](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75022/16459) over at [crypto.se]

Comment: If I'd generate the salt on the server side when a session is initiated. And communicate that salt to the clients connecting. Then I can generate the derived key for AES (using argon) fully client-side. Would that make it more secure?

Comment: And would it also be secure to generate a RSA keypair. Save the public key on the server. And only give the private keys to users allowed on the chat (e.g on a usb)?

Comment: *"Would that make it more secure?"* - more secure than what? Than plainly using the original password or having some weak KDF (i.e. simple hash) - yes.

Comment: *"Save the public key on the server. And only give the private keys to users allowed on the chat (e.g on a usb)"* - the point of the private key is to be private. Generating it on the server and giving it to the client clearly means that at least two parties (client and server) know the key.  So a big NO. Apart from that, this is a completely different question than you've originally asked. Please stay on topic.

Comment: How would the server know the private key? I'd manually generate the keypair, save the public.PEM on the server. And give the private.PEM on usb. The server would never know private.PEM

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood this since the "generating RSA keypair" came without context and I assumed that you generated the key on the server. Still, it is then "you" and the "user" who know the private key. And again - please stay within the context of the original question and there was nothing about any RSA keypairs.